# Azure Data Factory copy data - how do I save an http downloaded zip to blob store?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a simple copy data activity, with an HTTP connector source, and Azure Blob Storage as the sink. The file is a zip file so I am using a binary dataset for source and a binary for sink.

The data is properly fetched (I believe - looking at bytes transferred). However, I cannot save it to the Blob Store. In this scenario, you do not get to set the filename, only the path (container/directory). The filename used is the name of the file that I fetched.

However, the filename used in the sink step is prefixed with a backslash. It does not exist in the source, and I can find no way to remove it, and with a filename like that, I get a failure:

> Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorFailedFileOperation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Upload file failed at path extract/coEDW\XXXX_Data_etc.zip.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.,Source=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,StorageExtendedMessage=The specified resource does not exist. RequestId:bfe4e2f6-501e-002e-6a21-eaf10e000000 Time:2021-01-14T02:59:24.3300081Z,,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.,Source=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,'

(filename masked by me)

I am sure the fix is simple, but I cannot figure this out. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a dynamic file name for your Blob sink.

You can use the below example to see how to dynamically add a file name using variables:

In this example, the file name is having date and time fields to mark each file with their date and time.

[image]

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Same error - sink adds a backslash

Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorFailedFileOperation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Upload file failed at path extract/coEDW\XXXX_Data_December_2020.zip...

Comment: Ideally sink should not by itself add a backslash, are you adding a backslash at the last in FilePath, because as you can see above there are two blocks, one is to add a filepath, then after a backslash there's a block to add dynamic file name, try checking the filepath or can you paste it here, just change the folder names and keep the backslashes you added as is for me to check. Thanks!

Comment: I am not adding a backslash anywhere. I have tried fixed and dynamic filenames, as well as no file name (uses the source filename in this case).

However, I did create a new Linked Service to the Blob Store, and that fixed the problem. Why, I have no idea, but for now, I will just carry on with my work. Thanks for trying to solve this one for me.

Comment: That's great that your problem is solved. Maybe the earlier version of linked service might have some issue. If at all my reply helped you you can upvote if needed :) Thanks!